# jpeg burned into code editor in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, jpeg

I hope that somebody can help me out, otherwise I'm getting crazy soon.

A few hours ago I had a jpeg-file opened via windows photo viewer. after minimizing windows photo viewer to go back to my IDE (visual studio 2013) the image kind of burned into my editor. This is a strange behaviour and I never see something similiar like this before.

here is a list of steps that I tried to remove the issue:

- restarting my machine
- restarting my remote desktop connection
- restarting visual studio 2013
- resetting the window layout
- resetting all settings via Import and Export Settings Wizard
- changing the color theme from dark mode to light mode and back

the only thing that I didn't try out yet is to reinstall VS13.
Also a strange behaviour is that sometimes the image inside of the editor is flickering for a few seconds.

my question now is: how can I remove that issue AND how can something like this happen?

I hope you can help me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with reinstalling VS13.
Still don't know how it came to this behaviour.